# GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving fails for PersistFieldSql

Tags: haskell, newtype, forall

I'm trying to define a [Markdown](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/markdown-0.1.9/docs/Text-Markdown.html) newtype, and using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to automatically define new instances:

```
import Text.Markdown
import Yesod.Text.Markdown
import Database.Persist.Sql

newtype MarkdownNewT = MarkdownNewT { getMarkdown :: Markdown }
  deriving (Eq, IsString, Monoid, PersistField, PersistFieldSql)
```

This fails for the `PersistFieldSql` with the following message:

```
Could not coerce from ‘m Markdown’ to ‘m MarkdownNewT’
  because ‘m Markdown’ and ‘m MarkdownNewT’ are different types.
  arising from the coercion of the method ‘sqlType’ from type
               ‘forall (m :: * -> *). Monad m => m Markdown -> SqlType’ to type
               ‘forall (m :: * -> *). Monad m => m MarkdownNewT -> SqlType’
```

Is this due to the new [roles](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/users_guide/roles.html) features of GHC 7.8.2? In that particular case I don't know what to do, since Markdown is itself a newtype over Text...

Or is this related with the `forall` on `sqlType`? What is the reason for this error when all other instances are successfully automatically derived?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks very similar to some of the examples (in particular the `Vector` one) in the GHC wiki [Roles2](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Roles2) page of things that don't work with the current role system, alas.

Basically the problem is that in

```
class PersistField a => PersistFieldSql a where
    sqlType :: Monad m => m a -> SqlType
```

the monad `m` might be instantiated with a type constructor whose argument has nominal role, so that `m Markdown` and `m MarkdownNewT` *aren't* identically represented even if `Markdown` and `MarkdownNewT` themselves are - and the current role system has no way of restricting `m` to disallow such type constructors.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. In persistent 2, we switched over to using Proxy for exactly this reason.

Comment: Ørjan Johansen, thanks, I did stumble on that but your simple and concise explanation really helped!

Comment: Michael, so the solution for now would be to either define the PersistFieldSql manually or use Persistent 2, right?