# Can I derive a newtype instance of `Data`?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a newtype `T`:

```
newtype T = T Text
```

I want to derive `Data` for it. So with `-XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving -XDerivingStrategies` I do

```
deriving newtype instance Data T
```

I would expect this to be a no-brainer derivation for GHC yet I get a nasty error message (attached below). The error message seems to come from the application of `coerce` incurred by the `newtype` derivation.

If I understand role annotations correctly, they would need to go on the type declaration on the instance methods for `Data`, yet there are none. Do I need to roll my own instance?

```
    • Couldn't match representation of type ‘c1 Text’
                               with that of ‘c1 T’
        arising from a use of ‘ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Prim.coerce’
      NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to ‘c1’ have;
        we must assume that the role is nominal
    • In the expression:
        ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Prim.coerce
          @(forall (c :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep
                         -> TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
            forall (d :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep)
                   (b :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
            Data d => c (d -> b) -> d -> c b
            -> forall (g :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
               g -> c g
               -> Text -> c Text)
          @(forall (c :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep
                         -> TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
            forall (d :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep)
                   (b :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
            Data d => c (d -> b) -> d -> c b
            -> forall (g :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
               g -> c g
               -> T -> c T)
          gfoldl
      In an equation for ‘gfoldl’:
          gfoldl
            = ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Prim.coerce
                @(forall (c :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep
                               -> TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
                  forall (d :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep)
                         (b :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
                  Data d => c (d -> b) -> d -> c b
                  -> forall (g :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
                     g -> c g
                     -> Text -> c Text)
                @(forall (c :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep
                               -> TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
                  forall (d :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep)
                         (b :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
                  Data d => c (d -> b) -> d -> c b
                  -> forall (g :: TYPE ghc-prim-0.5.2.0:GHC.Types.LiftedRep).
                     g -> c g
                     -> T -> c T)
                gfoldl
      When typechecking the code for ‘gfoldl’
        in a derived instance for ‘Data T’:
        To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
      In the instance declaration for ‘Data T’
```

Possibly related: [GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving fails for PersistFieldSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893150/generalizednewtypederiving-fails-for-persistfieldsql)

EDIT: Perhaps I should just use `-XDeriveDataTypeable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=generalizednewtypederiving#a-more-precise-specification):

> A derived instance is derived only for declarations of these forms
>   (after expansion of any type synonyms):
>
> ```
> newtype T v1..vn                   = MkT (t vk+1..vn) deriving (C t1..tj)
> newtype instance T s1..sk vk+1..vn = MkT (t vk+1..vn) deriving (C t1..tj)
> ```
>
> where [...]
>
> - C is not `Read`, `Show`, `Typeable`, or `Data`. These classes should not “look through” the type or its constructor. You can still derive these
>     classes for a newtype, but it happens in the usual way, not via this
>     new mechanism. Confer with [Default deriving strategy](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=generalizednewtypederiving#default-deriving-strategy).

The point is: a `Data` instance for a `newtype` should be crafted according to the constructor of the `newtype` itself, rather than to the (several) constructors of the underlying type.

The generalized `newtype` instance would simply "coerce" the `Data` instance of the underlying type to the `newtype`, but that would be wrong.

(The error message you got could have been more helpful, though.)

Concluding: try to use `DeriveDataTypeable` instead. That should derive the right instance.

```
newtype T = T Text deriving (Data)
```

---

More precisely, we should see this in a proper instance:

```
> data U = A | B deriving Data
> newtype T = T U deriving Data
> toConstr (T A)
T
```

Instead, a "newtype derived" instance would yield `A` here, exposing the underlying constructor instead of the intended `T` one.

Comment: Great, thank you! Could you expand on the "should not" part? I understand that Typeable and friends exactly want to create a runtime representation of the types. Would it be totally illegitimate to have an instance that simply inherits this behavior from the derivee (if that's a word)? My main reason for introducing this newtype (in my specific case) is to squeeze a bit more type-safety out of the language by differentiating `T` and `Text`.

Comment: A case involving `Generic` where I think it's justifiable is `newtype Generically a = Generically a` which is a wrapper over `Generic`-behaviour (to be added to `GHC.Generics`). All of its instances inherit their behaviour from `Generic`, it is not unreasonable to do the same for `Generic` by newtype deriving it. This simplifies other instances by avoiding wrapping and unwrapping. It's a matter of philosophy